# Redirect to PHP page when countdown ends

Tags: jquery

Below is the code for a timer in my online test exam project. I want to redirect to `finish.php` when the timer ends. How can I do that?

```
       <!doctype html>
         <html>
        <head>

    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css"

     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'

      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
       <script src="src/jquery.missofis-countdown.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $( function() {
// default setup
     $( '#timer-countdown' ).countdown( {
     from: 60, // 3 minutes (3*60)
    to: 0, // stop at zero
    movingUnit: 1000, // 1000 for 1 second increment/decrements
    timerEnd: undefined,
    outputPattern: '$hour : $minute : $second',
    autostart: true
    } );
// count up
     $( '#timer-countup' ).countdown( {
    from: 0,
    to: 180 
   } );
// count in-between
     $( '#timer-countinbetween' ).countdown( {
    from: 30,
    to: 20 
    } );
// counter callback
$( '#timer-countercallback' ).countdown( {
    from: 10,
    to: 0,
         timerEnd: function() {
        this.animate( { 'opacity':.5 }, 500 ).css( { 'text-
         decoration':'line-through' } );
    } 
   } );
   // changed output patterns
    $( '#timer-outputpattern' ).countdown( {
    outputPattern: '$day Days $hour Hours $minute Miniuts $second Seconds',
    from: 60 * 60 * 24 * 3
     } );
       } );
   </script>
   </head>
  <body>


    <p class="timer-holder"><span id="timer-countdown"></span></p>







   </body>
  </html>
```

Below is the code for a timer in my online test exam project. I want to redirect to `finish.php` when the timer ends. How can I do that?

Comment: `window.location.assign('finish.php')`

Comment: Where i should put the above code?

Comment: In an anonymous function provided to whatever property is called by the plugin when the countdown ends.

Comment: please answer in a code i cant understand what u say

Comment: I can, but you haven't given enough detail in your question. Telling us what plugin you're using would be helpful.

Comment: below in answer i wrote the total code

Answer (score 2):

The `timerEnd` property takes a function which is called when the timer ends. You can put code in that function which redirects the page. Try this:

```
$('#timer-countdown').countdown({
    from: 60, // 3 minutes (3*60)
    to: 0, // stop at zero
    movingUnit: 1000, // 1000 for 1 second increment/decrements
    timerEnd: function() {
        window.location.assign('finish.php');
    },
    outputPattern: '$hour : $minute : $second',
    autostart: true
});
```

Comment: please anybody tell me the answer please

Comment: @sri Rory just explained you the answer, if you're just going to ignore it, and not even want to detail what's "not working", people will not be willing to help you. `window.location.assign('SOMEURL')` will make the redirection. If you replace `SOMEURL` by any page it will redirect. Just put that line after `<script type="text/javascript">` and you'll see how it redirects. If your countdown doesn't reach `timerEnd`, that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which plugin you have used in your code.But from my point of view,if you use jquery countdown plugin,then to redirect after finishing time,you can redirect by adding the on('finish.countdown',function(){});

Just try the following code if you want

```
$("#your_id").countdown({
     //do something here
 })
 .on('finish.countdown',function(){

     //redirect from here (document.location.href or whatever you want)

});
```

Thanks